# how can returning a type instead of a object be valid, misunderstanding a code fragment

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

I tried out boost msm lite which is a very nice state machine implementation. As always I try to understand how it is working and found a code fragment which I can't understand.

As a remark: I would not post the whole file from boost here, it is here: https://github.com/boost-experimental/sml/blob/f636c05cb1a483e5131348d59d6151453ca3f9f2/include/boost/msm-lite.hpp

The test code only for understanding the things behind the curtain:

```
 auto x2 = "test"_t;  //compiles fine!
```

That should go to this code fragment:

```
 template <class T, T... Chrs>
 auto operator""_t() BOOST_MSM_LITE_NOEXCEPT {
      return event<aux::string<Chrs...>>;       // ??? How this can work?
 }
```

My (mis)understanding here is, that it will return the `type` instead of a instance of the type? But it compiles... why?

`event` is defined as:

```
template <class>
struct event {

    template <class T, BOOST_MSM_LITE_REQUIRES(concepts::callable<bool, T>::value)>
        auto operator[](const T &t) const BOOST_MSM_LITE_NOEXCEPT {
            return transition_eg<event, T>{*this, t};
        }                                                                           template <class T, BOOST_MSM_LITE_REQUIRES(concepts::callable<void, T>::value)>
        auto operator/(const T &t) const BOOST_MSM_LITE_NOEXCEPT {
            return transition_ea<event, T>{*this, t}; 
        }   
};
```

The following example compiles fine:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/msm-lite.hpp"
namespace msm = boost::msm::lite;

int main()
{
    using namespace msm;
    auto x1 = "idle"_s;
    auto x2 = "test"_t;
}
```

Comment: Can't say why it compiles but it most definitely looks like a typo. Even more so when you consider `_s` returns `return state<aux::string<Chrs...>>{};`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Exactly what I think. But something is behind the curtain...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template <class T, T... Chrs>
auto operator""_t() BOOST_MSM_LITE_NOEXCEPT {
    return event<aux::string<Chrs...>>;       // ??? How this can work?
}
```

It works because this operator is not returning a type, but an instance of the template variable `event`, which is defined in [line 1536](https://github.com/boost-experimental/sml/blob/f636c05cb1a483e5131348d59d6151453ca3f9f2/include/boost/msm-lite.hpp#L1536-L1537):

```
template <class TEvent>
detail::event<TEvent> event{};
```

Template variables were only introduced in C++14, which is likely why this was harder for you to find and understand. Also note that the _s operator relies on [`state`](https://github.com/boost-experimental/sml/blob/f636c05cb1a483e5131348d59d6151453ca3f9f2/include/boost/msm-lite.hpp#L1542-L1543), which is not a template variable (thus why it has to be instantiated at the operator function).

Comment: This, to me, is *evil*

Comment: I was impressed myself. What previously was unmistakably admitted as an instance of a template class (e.g. `vector<int>`) could now be an actual object.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I hope people use a naming convention to indicate that a name represents a template variable. Just like `_t` is used to indicate a type alias, it will be nice if people use `_v` or something along those line to  indicate a variable. `event_v` would have been easier to grasp. Otherwise, I am with you on the *evil* part.

Comment: Thanks! I did not find the code part because my ctags did not find template variables :-) So I only go through the tag list in my editor and did not see the template for the variable... a normal grep returns to many "events" ;)

Comment: @RSahu This wouldn't be a problem if people would use `ThisStyle` for user-defined object types and `this_style` for instance names ;-) [also, I use `this_style_type` for type aliases, in case I ever start using POSIX...] Sadly for my opinion, the stdlib and Boost name `everything_like_this`, which means that many programmers follow their example, leading to opaque names everywhere.

Comment: @underscore_d, coming up with a naming convention and convincing others that it is a good one is rather hard.

Comment: @RSahu Of course. Stylistic preferences aside, my real point is that it would be better if we had some differentiation in the stdlib and other big libraries, rather than (mostly) `names_like_this` for pretty much every kind of entity, which as this thread shows, can make it difficult to understand what's going on.